# how to setting a log file location in windows server 2008?

Tags: windows-server-2008

I'm having the following script in windows 2003 task scheduler

```
C:\Admin\scripts\app1\sometask.Cmd > C:\Admin\scripts\app1\sometask.log
```

how do i achieve the same setting in windows server 2008 ? how do i set the sometask.log location in windows server 2008 ?

Answer (score 0):

Try exporting your task and try importing the same task on your server 2008.

Comment: Could you explain a little more? Perhaps, how to do this with step by step instructions?